# leetcode#24 Swap Nodes in Pairs runtime error (C language)

Tags: c, runtime-error

I try to answer the problem on [this link](https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/).
However, I find my answer works pretty good on a small number of inputs, but the leetcode website gives a runtime error on the input

> [4,77,57,79,24,47,21,42,38,54,26,28,30,85,32,40,62,28,89,37,24,3,51,72,59,49,7,60,44,7,27,48,37,37,27,13,36,49,55,26,55,33,55,85,19,39,25,33,68,14,70,44,70,73,68,29,22,27,89,66,35,69,67,24,58,94,37,46]

Here is my code, could anybody tell me what happened?

```
    /**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * struct ListNode {
     *     int val;
     *     struct ListNode *next;
     * };
     */
    struct ListNode* swapPairs(struct ListNode* head)
    {
        struct ListNode *dummy, *pi, *pj, *end;
        dummy->next = head;
        end = dummy;
        while(true){
            pi = end->next;    
            if(pi == NULL){
                break;
            }else{ 
                pj = pi->next;
            }
            if(pj == NULL){
                break;
            }
            end->next = pi->next;
            pi->next = pj->next;
            pj->next = pi;
            end = pi;
        }
        return dummy->next;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct ListNode *dummy, *pi, *pj, *end;
dummy->next = head;
```

you do not initialize `dummy` ptr, but you use it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a pretty low-level mistake i make.